# Scala: type mismatch error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala and I am practicing it with k-means algorithm following the tutorial from [k-means](https://spark-summit.org/2013/exercises/machine-learning-with-spark.html#running-the-program)

I am confused by this part of this tutorial:

```
var newCentroids = pointsGroup.mapValues(ps => average(ps)).collectAsMap()
```

This causes a type mismatch error because function `average` needs a `Seq`, while we give it an `Iterable`.  How can I fix this?  What caused this error?

Comment: I assume tutorial was written at the time of spark 0.9.0, when [`groupByKey` was returning `RDD[(K, Seq[V])]`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/api/core/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) while [now it's giving us `RDD[(K, Iterable[V])]`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could easily replace `Seq` with `Iterable` in provided solution for `average` function:

```
def average(ps: Iterable[Vector]) : Vector = {
  val numVectors = ps.size
  var out = new Vector(ps.head.elements)
  ps foreach ( out += _)
  out / numVectors
}
```

Or even in constant space:

```
def average(ps: Iterable[Vector]): Vector = {
  val numVectors = ps.size

  val vSize = ps.head.elements.length

  def element(index: Int): Double = ps.map(_(index)).sum / numVectors

  new Vector(0 until vSize map element toArray)
}
```

Comment: your answer is so amazing! if it is ok to you, can you recommend some light-weighted book or other things, that i can get entry level idea about scala? i searched web and get mess of information, that makes me confused

Comment: @G_cy There are lot of ways to do it at http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/

If you want my humble opinion - get some IDE with tips like Intellij IDEA with scala plugin and do small real tasks,while lurking docs and asking questions here

[This course](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun) from the language creator is also great

Comment: that what I am doing. Do you think Intellij is better than eclipse? I am using eclipse, and I get different wired problems. That makes me crazy.

Comment: @G_cy eclipse have huge plugins repository, a lot of vendors provides tools\compilations for eclipse, but Idea provides somehow more joyful less buggy and frustrating out-of-the-box experience. So, i think eclipse is better for companies\experts, Idea is better for newbies\small teams.

Answer (score 4):

Well `Seq` is a sub-type of `Iterable` but not vice-versa, so it is not possible to convert these types in the type systems.

There is an explicit conversion available by writing `average(ps.toSeq)`. This conversion will iterate the `Iterable` and collect the items into a `Seq`.

Comment: thx for your answer! could recommend some efficient articles to me to get essential information idea about scala. someone recommended me the book: scala for the impatient. is it a good choice?

Comment: Do both of the coursera classes (start with functional programming), then proceed to write code, read the book of the language creator, start to read the docs, learn some libraries written in scala that are in your area of interest (akka, specs, finagle, kafka, scalaz, spark...). Start to work through the book "functional programming in scala" by manning (it is often on sale for 50%).

Comment: Also you can go join the #scala channel on freenode IRC, people will help you there and there are interesting discussions regarding topics from beginner to expert level.